# Fill cell based on another in Excel

Tags: excel

I would like to fill in a cell according to what I filled in another.
EX:

[image]

Comment: Try, ="HELLO "&A2&"!"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Concatenate the string using `&`

```
="HELLO "&A2&"!"
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two options 1) using & symbol `="HELLO "&A1&"!"` or 2) using CONCAT function `=CONCAT("HELLO ", A2, "!")` both methods work the same so whatever is easier for you.

Comment: Note that using the `Concat` function may cause reverse compatibility issues, as the `Concat` function was introduced in Office 2016